# Print between two regex using awk only

Tags: bash, awk

I am lost while figuring out a way to print between two strings. Both these strings contain special characters like `<,>`.

I am able to achieve this using `sed` flawlessly (but cannot use), but I am in need of `awk` as I need to take further text manipulation over the result.

Here is sample file:

```
$ cat input.txt
RANDOM CLI> THIS IS BEFORE WINDOW
RANDOM CLI>
RANDOM CLI>log list all show... 
bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bal
bla bla bla bla
RANDOM CLI>
RANDOM CLI>
RANDOM CLI>THIS IS OUT OF WINDOW
```

I am intrested in text between *"RANDOM CLI>log list all show..."* and next *"RANDOM CLI>"*

This can be do ne using sed, like below:

```
$ sed -n '/CLI>log/,/ CLI>/p' cli
RANDOM CLI>log list all show...
bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bal
bla bla bla bla
RANDOM CLI>
```

But as I mention, `sed` is not suitable for my requirement and need an `awk` only solution.

Some attempts to escape special characters but no help.

```
awk '/CLI>log/,/ CLI>/' input.txt
RANDOM CLI>log list all show...

awk '/CLI\>log/,/CLI\>/' input.txt 

awk '/CLI>log/{f=1;for (i=0;i<=NR;i++){getline}}/CLI>/{f=0}f' cli
```

Comment: There is nothing special about the characters `<,>`. Your first awk attempt MAKES `>` "special" by escaping it so in GNU awk or GNU sed that would turn it into a word boundary. Do not consider using getline until you know awk MUCH better, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: @EdMorton  thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic awk range isn't working because pattern `CLI>`is found in starting range as well thus causing awk to stop printing after first line only.

You can anchored regex to print full range:

```
awk '/ CLI>log/,/ CLI>$/' input.txt

RANDOM CLI>log list all show...
bla bla
bla bla
bla bla bal
bla bla bla bla
RANDOM CLI>
```

Otherwise using awk you can also do:

```
awk 'p && / CLI>/{print; p=0} / CLI>log/{p=1} p' input.txt
```

This command uses a toggle flag `p` to decide whether to print or not. `p` is set to `1` when we get `CLI>log` in a line. We keep printing till we get next `CLI>` text while `p==1`. Once we get it we just print closing line and set `p` to `0` so that we stop printing.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thanks ...Can you please tell me why basic awk range was not working ? `awk '/pat1/,/pat2/' file` also ,some description to your solution ?

Comment: Added an explanation in my answer about range.

Comment: thanks for your help. Although if you add description to your solution then it would be very helpful.

Comment: Added further explanation.